# Shippo API error on import

Tags: php, ups, shippo

We are implementing the shipping API from Shippo. On exports everything seems to work, but on import we get the following error from UPS in test mode:

> 120120: Hard: The country associated with Shippers ShipperNumber must be the same as the shipments Shippers country.

We did notice the same error reported on the UPS developer forum, but no solution was given. Shippo say UPS must enable import on my account. UPS says:

> Your account is active and enable for every function.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that your UPS account is not enabled for shipments from the outbound country you have requested. While your UPS account number might be enabled "for every function" (e.g. rating, label purchase, pickup, etc.) it might not be enabled for all outbound countries.

I'd recommend you reach out to UPS and ask how to to get your account enabled for shipments from this country. It's not unlikely that you'll get a separate account number for this country.

Comment: Thank you for your input Simon. Let's hope we can have imports enabled from a single account as we will do import from virtually any country.